# Angular JS Routing - Links inside SPA

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have created a project with index.html with certain links to other pages. My routing works as intended but I'm wondering what's the best approach to go with when it comes to links on other pages.

To clarify it:

My index.html page has routes:

Feed
Bblog
Marketplace
Recruiting
Adverts

Now what I'm curious about is how do I for example route links inside these pages.

For example, my Bblog page has tabs which I want to be opened inside the same page. Now for example whenever I click some tab link, it redirects me to my index.html since my .otherwise route is set to /.

Comment: Any reason you Un answered?

Comment: Sorry my friend, I didn't realise I did that, I wanted to do opposite but it seams it was already upped. Fixed now :)

Comment: Ah.ok.no worries. Just wondered if you found a different way :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what engine or library you're using for your routing. Though I faced the same requirement not too long ago.

We're using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for our routing. It's very similar to Angulars routing.

A snippet from our routing table contains something similar to this.

```
$stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: '/views/index',
            })
            .state('orders', {
                url: '/orders',
                templateUrl: '/views/orders',
            })
            .state('orderdetail', {
                url: '/orders/detail/:id',
                templateUrl: '/views/orderdetail',
            })
            .state('orderdetail.address', {
                url: '/:addressId',
                templateUrl: '/views/orderdetail',
            })
```

Essentially you use the .dot notation to separate nested views. So the `orderdetail.address` is nested inside the `orderdetail`

This means that the routing above will go something allow you to see an overview of order details at `/orders/detail/myOrderId` and drill further in to, say, an address by visiting `/orders/detail/myOrderId/myaddressId`

If you're using `ui-router` then you will get more info on nested views [on this link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)

If you're using angular `ngRoute` then the `[ngRoute][3]` docs and supporting [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) demonstrate how to stack up the routes.

So (from the plunker) -

```
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
     .when('/Book/:bookId', {
      templateUrl: 'book.html',
      controller: 'BookController',
      resolve: {
        // I will cause a 1 second delay
        delay: function($q, $timeout) {
          var delay = $q.defer();
          $timeout(delay.resolve, 1000);
          return delay.promise;
        }
      }
    })
    .when('/Book/:bookId/ch/:chapterId', {
      templateUrl: 'chapter.html',
      controller: 'ChapterController'
    });
```

this will give you `/book/myBookId` and `/book/myBoodId/ch/myChapterId`